# Poderia adicionar um campo UNIQUE que aceita nulos?

Tags: sql, postgresql, modelagem, restrição-único

### Eu posso criar um campo que aceita nulos e dizer que ele é único?

Essa minha tabela, o CRM indica que é médico e não pessoa normal, ele tem que ser único, mas tem que permitir nulos. Esse campo também é chave estrangeira em outra tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou ainda projetando um diagrama e em seguida criarei no PostgreSQL.

Esse era meu primeiro modelo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observando os comentários, fiz umas alterações e ficou assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas com essa ligação entre pessoas e especialidade, me parece que o CRM pode ser repetido para pessoas diferentes, posso estar errado, mas essa impressão que ficou.

Comment: Se bem me lembro das aulas de modelagem, você deveria criar uma tabela de especialização de pessoas e lá teria crm

Comment: Sim você pode porque um valor `nulo` nunca é igual a outro. Tente explicar o cenario onde isso vai ser aplicado.

Comment: Entendo, mas talvez eu deva mudar minha modelagem

Comment: Poderia mostrar qual seria o relacionado do campo `crm` com a outra tabela? sugiro também que adicione a tag modelagem, pelo menos quando vi a pergunta me concentrei na parte "posso ter um campo unique nulo" e parece que sua pergunta é "vou ter algum problema com um unique key nula nessa modelagem".

Comment: Editei a pergunta, da uma olhada

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O PostgreSQL permite que uma coluna seja nula mesmo que tenha uma restrição de `UNIQUE` já que o valor `NULL` é excepcional e nunca é igual a outros nulos. Não há nada que impeça o que você está fazendo.

Você só teria problemas se tentar fazer isto em chave primária, o que não é o caso.

Há uma corrente que defende que uma tabela nunca deveria ter nulos. Isto é um pouco radical mas faz algum sentido. Analise e veja o que vai funcionar melhor para você.

[Documentação](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS).

Só um adendo, não vejo com bons olhos o uso do tipo `int` para guardar RG ou CRM, estes dados não são números, eles, por acaso só possuem dígitos. Na verdade o RG possui caracteres. Inteiros devem ser usados quando você tem valores numéricos de verdade, quando você vai fazer cálculos com ele e não estão sendo usados apenas como identificadores, descritores de uma informação. O mesmo critério que te levou fazer o CPF ser `varchar` e talvez pudesse ser até `char`, deveria nortear os demais campos identificadores. Parece que você vai gravar os pontos e traço no CPF, isto também não é uma boa ideia, isto é formatação e não informação. Formatação não deveria ir parar no banco de dados.

Seria algo assim:

```
CREATE TABLE TBPessoa (
    id integer,
    nome varchar(45),
    nascimento datetime,
    rg char(11),
    cpf char(11),
    sexo char(1),
    crm char(8),
    UNIQUE (crm)
);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Create/UniqueNull.sql).

Comment: olha o edit que eu fiz

Comment: Olhei, você quer que eu faça algo com esta informação? Ela não parece acrescentar nada à pergunta original. Se deseja fazer uma nova pergunta, abra um nova pergunta.

Comment: Ok, eu estava tornando a pergunta uma bagunça, mas a resposta me ajudou, e a questão dos nulos, concordo, organizei de uma forma melhor, e resolvi o problema, obrigado pela resposta

Comment: @LucasMotta relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53296/101