# Tabelas com colunas sempre null

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

É considerado errado criar tabelas com colunas mutuamente exclusivas? Por exemplo, tenho as tabelas `Texto`, `Trecho` e `Linhas`, sendo que `Texto` e `Trecho` tem muitas `Linhas`, a tabela `Linha` fica sendo detentora das duas FK mantendo sempre uma delas `null`.

Esta é a melhor abordagem para a situação? Talvez como uma segunda solução poderia ser criado uma tabela intermediária `Linhas` que é referenciada por `Linha`, `Texto` e `Trecho` economizando assim um campo na tabela `Linha`, que é de longe a mais volumosa, mas como contraponto dificultando as operações de busca.

Qual destas, ou até mesmo outras, formas devem ser usadas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estritamente falando de fato colunas mutualmente exclusivas não são desejáveis e pode sim ser considerado errado.

Isto não quer dizer que você nunca deva fazer e que os resultados adequados não podem ser obtidos se fizer "errado".

Nem sempre vale à pena complicar a modelagem por causa de um detalhe para dizer que fez o "certo". A regra pela regra nunca é boa, ela precisa servir a um propósito. Se uma porção de gente experiente talvez apoiada por estudos seguem uma regra, deve haver um bom motivo e se você pode fazer o mesmo sem criar dificuldades, faça, mas não faça cegamente sem analisar se não terá um custo que não pode ou não deve pagar.

Separar dados em outras tabelas, [normalizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) tem um custo de desenvolvimento e de processamento para trazer as informações todas as vezes que precisar. Precisa compensar para tomar esta decisão.

Uma pergunta que deve-se fazer para achar uma outra solução no caso das colunas serem mutualmente exclusivas é o que acontece se aproveitar a mesma coluna para os dois dados? Em alguns casos isto pode se tornar um problema, pode dificultar o desenvolvimento, talvez exija um campo extra para dizer o que está cadastrado ali. Mas pode compensar. Não é a solução mais correta, mas ela é válida em alguns casos.

Outra pergunta que deve ser feita é qual o problema você terá por ter nulos. Há uma corrente que diz que nenhuma coluna deveria ter nulos. Isto é radical, me parece academicismo, mas faz algum sentido. Eu acho que nulo é um valor perfeitamente "válido" (ik, ele quer dizer que é um valor inválido, mas é válido de usar para representar isso). Não gosto muito dele, prefiro evitá-lo, mas não descartaria, pode facilitar.

Note que em quase todos os bancos de dados (provavelmente todos *mainstream*) uma coluna não utilizada (nula) ocupa bem pouco espaço - zero ou um *byte* - então não se preocupe com o espaço ocupado que hoje não é problema mais. A organização dos dados é mais importante.

O quanto vai prejudicar a performance e desenvolvimento de suas consultas? O volume de consultas será muito grande? Esta perda é aceitável? Muitas vezes é, outras não. [*Desnormalização*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101) consciente é uma ferramenta útil. Não deve ser abusada, poucas vezes traz resultados tão importantes assim mas ela não deve ser descartada porque não é o mais correto. Em alguns casos não é questão de *desnormalizar*, é não normalizar o que não era para ser.

Só você, no seu caso específico, pode dizer qual será melhor neste caso. E prepare-se para ter que mudar no futuro. O que pode servir bem um dia pode não servir mais em outro. E este é um dos motivos para se usar [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e ter códigos canônicos para acessar o banco de dados. Assim precisa mudar em apenas um lugar quando a modelagem mudar.

O mais importante você está fazendo, está questionando qual é o melhor. Se você ainda não tem muita experiência tem chance de errar mas será um ganho de alguma forma, na próxima talvez não erre mais. Ou talvez erre para o outro lado porque não percebeu que a próxima é uma situação um pouco diferente. Faz parte do processo de aprendizado.

Mas se quer uma resposta "objetiva" que é um pouco melhor que um cara ou coroa, normalize, implemente a alternativa que está sugerindo. Mas pense no que é correto do ponto de vista semântico, se preocupe menos com o mecanismo. Tente ver se o modelo pede para ser normalizado, se é natural ter esta coluna separada.